# Con Aggregation - Project, ¿cómo agregar un campo relacionado dentro de esa colección?

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql, aggregate

¿Cómo puedo hacer para en la funcionalidad `$project` agregarle un campo relacionado desde otra colección, o qué debo utilizar para que me salga este campo?

```
resultados.$project
{

  "numero_votos":1,
  "Candidato":1, ( hasta aqui me funciona )

  "Candidato,Partido,nombre":1,
 
}
```

*candidato* tiene una relación con la colección *partido*, y necesito que me aparezca el campo *nombre* del partido.

Comment: que es `resultados` que almacena? que consulta haces previamente? ya estás obteniendo de alguna manera los datos de la otra colección relacionada?

Answer (score 0):

Entonces, tienes 2 colecciones: Candidato y partido. Candidato tiene un partido.

Pueba con ésta lógica siguiente:

```
db.candidato.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'partido',    //  join con colección partido
            localField: '_id_de_collection_partido_en_candidato',
            foreignField: '_id_principal_en_collection_partido',
            as: 'lookPartido'
        }
    }, { $unwind: "$lookPartido" }
    .project({
        'Candidato': "nombre_del_candidato",
        'Partido': "$lookPartido.nombre_partido",
        'Nombre': "etc_etc"
    })
    .sort({ _id: -1 })
    .limit(100)
```